# Is it possible to use a twilio number for whatsapp verification on BlueStacks?

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, bluestacks

I installed bluestacks and whatsapp in it on my pc, sent the verification code to my twilio account, however I'm not receiving any confirmation code sms. If I send a normal sms from my phone to the twilio number it is received and displayed normally in the logs, but the whatsapp verification message isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are many [reasons you may not be receiving SMS messages to your Twilio number](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133447-Not-Receiving-Incoming-SMS-and-MMS-Messages-on-Twilio-Phone-Number). In this case it is likely that WhatsApp are trying to send the message using a short code or alphanumeric sender ID. It's also possible that WhatsApp refuses to send verification codes to VOIP numbers, like Twilio numbers. In general it is not a good practice to use Twilio numbers to receive verification codes.

There is [more discussion on this sort of thing on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63160496/im-unable-to-use-a-twilio-phone-number-for-apple-two-factor-authentication).

Comment: I understand, I'm probably gonna have to request the ability to receive sms from shortocde numbers manually then. Ty

Comment: It's still not guaranteed to arrive, but good luck!

Comment: Did this work for you @Dravis800

Comment: Delayed answer I know, but in the end due to our necessities we opted to use a different App completely.